# Add a meta header to an aspx file?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, metadata, code-behind

We have a couple of e-commerce pages that are coded and maintained in `aspx`. I made some changes to the page but some of the characters are not appearing as they should  and this is because the header for the page is missing the following meta

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I went into the page but I have not been able to locate the header for the file or where its pulling it from, all I have is this

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="Sample.aspx.vb" Inherits="AMEX.Web.Sample" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc1" Namespace="Generic.Foundation.WebControls" Assembly="Generic.Foundation.WebControls" %>
```

I been trying to locate  the `vb` file but no luck. Is there anyway to know the default locations for these files? Is there way to add the metadata from the page to the header (*I know this is a no-no, but wanted to ask*)

Comment: The vb files should be in the same folder as their corresponding aspx files.

Comment: That `<meta>` tag should go in the `<head>` section in the file. Or are you saying that what you have shown is the entire "Sample.aspx" file?

Comment: @PradeepKumar that is what I thought too, but there are no `vb` files in the folder. @ AndrewMorton As for the `<meta>` I know it must go in the header but I cannot find the header. What I posted is the initial part of the file, the remainder is the `<body>` of the page.

Comment: The Codebehind="Sample.aspx.vb" indicates where the file is, so there has to be a file at that location, or else the application would not run.  Also, is the site using master pages?

Comment: @Tavo Have you tried adding a `<head>` section? Or setting the headers which IIS supplies, e.g. [How to: Select an Encoding for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39d1w2xf.aspx)?

Comment: @BrianMains I wondered about it having a master page, but I thought it would then have a `MasterPageFile` entry in the `<%@ Page %>` section.

Comment: You would - my theory is maybe it was missing?

Comment: @AndrewMorton thank you for the page. By setting the globalization in the `web.config` file did the job! Thanks!

Comment: @Tavo I made it into an answer for you so that if the MSDN page changes its location then others in the future can still see the essential part of it here.

Comment: @Tavo, If there is no vb file in the folder corresponding to your aspx file, then it simply means that the web application is compiled/published. In such cases the executable code goes into a DLL file in the `bin` folder.

Comment: @PradeepKumar I found the bin folder, but now I need to figure out which dll needs to be edited to include the meta tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the content-type for all pages on the web site in one go by using settings in "web.config".

Referring to the MSDN article [How to: Select an Encoding for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39d1w2xf.aspx), you would find the `<system.web>` section (or create one if it is not there) and add (or modify) the `<globalization>` section to include

```
<globalization
  requestEncoding="utf-8" 
  responseEncoding="utf-8"
/>
```

Alternatively, if you want to set the encoding on each page, you can add it to the `<%@ Page %>` directive:

```
<%@ Page RequestEncoding="utf-8" ResponseEncoding="utf-8" %>
```